# GWT code is not rendered correctly when first time opened in IE

Tags: css, gwt

I have my GWT application with TabLayoutPanel and when I load it in Chrome, everything is fine. But when I first load it in ie9 I don't get the full page: several labels and images on the first tab didn't load. But when I create the second tab and then open the first one, everything is fine. I found some questions about this on this site that the code is correct. The problem must be in  first time uploading css. I compared the code in Chrome and IE(first load and after creating the second tab in TabLayoutPanel) and here are the results

**Chrome**

```
<head> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject/Upload.css">
   <style>
      #loader{position:fixed;......A LOT OF STYLES...
   </style>
</head> 
<body style="margin: 0px;">
```

**IE (first load)**

```
<head> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject/Upload.css">
   <style></style>
   <style></style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<iframe>
   ...
   <div style="height: 0px;">
   ...
   <div style="top: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
</iframe>
```

**IE (after creating the second tab in TabLayoutPanel)**

```
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject/Upload.css">
   <style></style>
   <style></style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<iframe>
   ...
   <div style="height: 68px;">
   ...
   <div style="top: 68px; bottom: 221px;">
</iframe>
```

Help me please. What should I do? I need that the page loaded correctly in the first loading.

**Java Code**

```
    public void onModuleLoad() {
       startAuthApplication();
}
    private void startAuthApplication() {
         AppController appController = new AppController();
         appController.go(RootLayoutPanel.get());
    }
/********************************************************************/
            public class AppController{
                public void go(final HasWidgets container) {
                    SystemPresenter systemPresenter = new SystemPresenter(AppFactory.getSystemView());
                    systemPresenter.go(container);
                }
            }
/********************************************************************/
        public class SystemPresenter{
        private final SystemView systemView;

            public SystemPresenter(SystemView systemView) {
                this.systemView = systemView;
            }

            public void go(HasWidgets container) {
                container.clear();
                container.add(systemView.asWidget());
            }
        }
/********************************************************************/
    public class AppFactory {
        private static SystemView systemView;
        private static TabPanelViewImpl tabPanelView;

        public static SystemView getSystemView() {
            if (systemView == null) {
                systemView = new SystemViewImpl();
            }
            return systemView;
        }

        public static TabPanelViewImpl getTabPanelView() {
            if (tabPanelView == null) {
                tabPanelView = new TabPanelViewImpl();
            }
            return tabPanelView;
        }
    }
/********************************************************************/
    public class SystemViewImpl extends Composite implements SystemView {

        interface Binder extends UiBinder<DockLayoutPanel, SystemViewImpl> {
        }

        private static Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

        @UiField(provided = true)
        TabPanelViewImpl tabPanelView;

        public SystemViewImpl() {
            tabPanelView = AppFactory.getTabPanelView();
            initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
        }
    }
/********************************************************************/
public class TabPanelViewImpl extends Composite implements TabPanelView,
        DocListEditDraftEventHandlers {

    interface TabPanelViewImplBinder extends
            UiBinder<TabLayoutPanel, TabPanelViewImpl> {
    }

    private static TabPanelViewImplBinder binder = GWT
            .create(TabPanelViewImplBinder.class);
    private TabPanelPresenter presenter;

    @UiField(provided = true)
    TabLayoutPanel tabPanel;

    private DocListTableView docListTableView;

    public TabPanelViewImpl() {
        super();
        tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(30, Unit.PX);
        docListTableView = AppFactory.getDocListTableView();
        tabPanel.add(docListTableView, "List of Docs");
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
/********************************************************************/
public class DocListTableView extends Composite {

    interface DocListTableViewUiBinder extends
    UiBinder<Widget, DocListTableView> {
    }

    private static DocListTableViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(DocListTableViewUiBinder.class);

    private final DocListTableConstants constants = GWT
            .create(DocListTableConstants.class);

    private final Resources resources = GWT.create(Resources.class);

    private final DocListTableResources resource = GWT
            .create(DocListTableResources.class);

    @UiField(provided = true)
    CellTable<DocList> cellTable;

    @UiField
    Label emptyLabel;
    @UiField(provided = true)
    Label userLabel;

    public DocListTableView() {
        userLabel = new Label("User: "
                + AppFactory.getUserInfo().getUserName());
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
/********************************************************************/
```

**DocListTableView.ui.xml**

```
<ui:with field="res"
        type="com.myproject.client.resources.DocListTableConstants" />
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
        <g:north size='5'>
            <g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{docListStyle.center}">
                <g:HorizontalPanel width="100%">
                    <g:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_LEFT">
                        <g:Label addStyleNames="{docListStyle.label}" ui:field="userLabel" />
                    </g:cell>
                </g:HorizontalPanel>
                <g:HorizontalPanel width="100%">
                    <g:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER">
                        <g:Label addStyleNames="{docListStyle.label} {docListStyle.centerLabel}"
                            text="{res.label}" />
                    </g:cell>
                </g:HorizontalPanel>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:north>
        <g:center>
            <g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{docListStyle.center1}">
                <g:HorizontalPanel width="100%">
                    <g:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER">
                        <g:Label ui:field="emptyLabel" visible="false">Your document list is empty</g:Label>
                    </g:cell>
                </g:HorizontalPanel>

                <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign='top'>
                            <ct:CellTable addStyleNames='{docListStyle.panel1}'
                                ui:field='cellTable' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center'>
                            <my:DocListSimplePager ui:field='pager'
                                visible="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:center>
        <g:south size='10'>
            <g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{docListStyle.center}">
                <g:Label addStyleNames="{docListStyle.label}               {docListStyle.centerLabel}"
                    text="{res.status}" />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <g:Image url="images/status/draft.png"></g:Image>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="{docListStyle.label}">
                                <ui:text from='{res.draft}' />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <g:Image url="images/status/accept.png"></g:Image>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="{docListStyle.label}">
                                <ui:text from='{res.accept}' />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <g:Image url="images/status/send.png"></g:Image>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="{docListStyle.label}">
                                <ui:text from='{res.send}' />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <g:Image url="images/status/get.png"></g:Image>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="{docListStyle.label}">
                                <ui:text from='{res.get}' />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:south>
    </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

I know I posted a lot of code, but I hope it quite understanding. I add `DocListTableView` on the first tab of `TabLayoutPanel` and in `DocListTableView.ui.xml` file only celltable+pager display in first load. The other `Labels` and `<table>` element doesn't show up.

**Edit**
Interface `Resources` and `DocListTableResources` I use in cellTable and they render correctly.

```
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;

public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

    @Source("draft.png")
    ImageResource draft();

    @Source("edit.png")
    ImageResource edit();
...
}
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable;

public interface DocListTableResources extends CellTable.Resources {
    public interface DocListTableStyle extends CellTable.Style {
    };

    @Override
    @Source({ "DocListTableStyle.css" })
    DocListTableStyle cellTableStyle();

}
```

**Edit2**

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.ConstantsWithLookup;

public interface DocListTableConstants extends ConstantsWithLookup {
    public String label();

    public String status();

    public String draft();
...
```

Comment: Please, show your java code too. How are you adding the TabLayoutPanel to interface?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's actually going wrong - is the `DocListTableView` not getting added at all during the initial add? Or only the resources in it? Can you show how you are using the `resources` and `resource` fields from `DocListTableView`? Without more information, it's hard to tell - maybe you just need a call to `ensureInjected()` on your style or add your `DocListTableView` in `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()`.

Comment: @Igor Klimer, I edited my question. And you propose `ensureInjected()` or `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()`. Can you help me to use it well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, but I found the error by myself.

In `DocListTableView.ui.xml` I use `DockLayoutPanel` and set it size in `EM`.

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
```

There is a [problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/yPdM13GXO_M/cELkQjsKg64J) with IE with using `EM`. So I tried to use `PX` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If the tabs loads properly the second time you trigger it, there might some kind of race condition going on when the view is initially created and populated. In such cases, [`Scheduler.scheduleDeferred`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29) usually helps:

> A deferred command is executed after the browser event loop returns.

Meaning, the code in the callback will be executed when the view is created and added to the DOM.

As to *where* this call is needed - I can only guess, you know your code best :) I'd start with:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        tabPanel.add(docListTableView, "List of Docs");
    }
});
```

Comment: `Sheduler.sheduleDeferred` didn't work for me. But I found out something else. The elements, that didn't load on the first time are those who work with `<ui:with field="res" type="com.myproject.client.resources.DocListTableConstants" />`. For example, <g:Label ui:field="emptyLabel" visible="false">Your document list is empty</g:Label> load correctly, but `<g:Label addStyleNames="{docListStyle.label} {docListStyle.centerLabel}" text="{res.status}" />` doesn't load in `DocListTableView.ui.xml`

Comment: Hmm, well that's weird.. but also easy to test :) Just replace `{res.status}` with a static text and see if that makes the label render properly the first time. If that's the case, then you might have stumbled upon a bug in GWT.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. I found the problem. In `DocListTableView.ui.xml` I use `DockLayoutPanel`. When I replaced it with `HTMLPanel`, all elements loaded corectly. Maybe there is some particular qualities in addind `DockLayoutPanel` in `TabLayoutPanel`.